# Finding eigenvalues and eigenstates

Tags: matrices, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

I am currently taking a course in Quantum Mechanics and I am getting confused by the start of this question, I'm sure it's fairly simple but I'm not getting it.

The question is:

A quantum mechanical system is described by a two dimensional Hilbert space of states, spanned by an orthonormal basis $ |\alpha\rangle,|\beta\rangle $, with the following Hamiltonian:

$$ H|\alpha\rangle = 4|\alpha\rangle + |\beta\rangle , H|\beta\rangle = |\alpha\rangle+4|\beta\rangle $$

I need to first find the eigenvalues and eigenstates of the hamiltonian.
My intuition tells me this is possible without directly working out the matrix, but I would also like to know the matrix. I also know that $|\alpha\rangle$ and $|\beta\rangle$ are orthogonal, since a quantum hamiltonian is hermitian and admits and orthogonal basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little rusty at physics but this this looks like a simple enough linear algebra problem. Your intuition is correct in that it's relatively easy to guess an eigenstate.

\begin{align*}
H(|\alpha\rangle + |\beta\rangle)&=
H|\alpha\rangle+H|\beta\rangle=
4|\alpha\rangle+|\beta\rangle+|\alpha\rangle+4|\beta\rangle=
5(|\alpha\rangle + |\beta\rangle)\\
H(|\alpha\rangle - |\beta\rangle)&=
H|\alpha\rangle-H|\beta\rangle=
4|\alpha\rangle+|\beta\rangle-(|\alpha\rangle+4|\beta\rangle)=
3(|\alpha\rangle - |\beta\rangle)\\
\end{align*}

The matrix is $\left[\begin{matrix}4 & 1\\1&4\end{matrix}\right]$

It is constructed by stacking column vectors made from the coefficients in the equations of the Hamiltonian you wrote.

Comment: My initial gut feeling was to contract the matrix in the way you mentioned at the bottom, I actually did this in order to complete the rest of the question. It didn't really sit right with my however, so thought I'd clarify. Thanks for the response!